# Blocking or Non-blocking (getting a ConnectionError: Connection is closed randomly) nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am working on a controller/route that will make a MSSQL call and return a string depending on the row count I got the logic working, but when I call the endpoint several times (hitting F5 in my browser a lot), I will randomly get a "ConnectionError: Connection is closed." error. Any ideas to refactor this code to be less blocking?

```
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  var command = req.query.moncd;

  if (command == null){
    res.send('ERROR');
  }

  switch(command.toLowerCase()){

    case 'case1':
      sql.connect(config, function(err) {

        var request = new sql.Request();
        request.query('SELECT COUNT(*) as count FROM table', function(err, recordset) {

           if (err != undefined){
             status = err;

           }else{
            if (recordset[0].count === 0){
               status = OK;
             }else{
               status = NOT_OK;
             }
             console.dir(status); 
           }

      });

        res.send(status);
      });

    break;
    default:
      res.send('Command not implemented');
      break; 
  }
});
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with blocking. You need to close the connections that you have open and/or pool connections. When your refresh a few times you are creating new connections but not closing old ones which is exhausting the available connections that mssql has which means any new ones get closed immediately.

Comment: I added a sql.close() command and I am still seeing the same issues. Am I not using the connection pooling correctly?